# Tkinter Notebook widget not working as expected

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

I'm trying to write a simple tkinter application with two frames and a controller. However when I try to implement the Notebook widget in the controller, it seems to do nothing.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class WrapFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__(root)


class UnwrapFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__(root)


class Controller(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__(root)

        # Notebook
        notebook = ttk.Notebook(self)

        wrap_frame = WrapFrame(notebook)
        unwrap_frame = UnwrapFrame(notebook)

        notebook.add(wrap_frame, text="Wrap")
        notebook.add(unwrap_frame, text="Unwrap")
        notebook.pack()


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title('Mod')
        self.geometry('300x200')
        self.resizable(False, False)


app = App()
Controller(app)
app.mainloop()
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Answer (score 2):

`Controller` is a frame. You never call `pack`, `place`, or `grid` on the instance of `Controller`. Since it's not visible, everything in it won't be visible either.

You need to do something like this:

```
controller = Controller(app)
controller.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```